# how to read large XLSX file in nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular, xlsx

I have used ts-xlsx node side. I am reading the data from front-end using file-reader as byte array then sending the byte array and using lib to process the data. In small amount of data it takes less time but if data is big then it take too much time to get the response. Can anyone tell me efficient way.

on frontend :-

```
let file: File = evt.target.files[0];
     let reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
     reader.onload = (e) => {
       this.csv = reader.result;
       this.isUpload = true;
     }
     reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
```

on node side :-

```
var data = XLSX.read(this.csv, { type: "binary" });
const wsname = data.SheetNames[0];
const ws = data.Sheets[wsname];
const bdata = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, {raw:true});
```

Comment: we need yo see your code in order to help

Comment: @AmitWagner code added

Comment: remove the front end rendering and just sent the file. in the server i dont see any special processing so there isn't a lot you can do.

Comment: @AmitWagner it is taking too much time at server side when it convert the worksheet to json thats the main problem what i am facing.

Comment: well if its a big file then it will take time. what you can do is to work with a stream. 
process each row and send it to the front. in your front handle this stream row by row and dont wait the whole request to finish

Answer (score 0):

var data = XLSX.readFile(this.csv, { type: "binary" }); // read => readFile